# Maximum bin load for $\alpha n$ balls into $n$ bins

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

In a paper I am reading the author writes:

> A standard result concerning balls and bins shows that if we throw at least $\alpha n$ balls into at most $n$ bins, then the maximum bin load is $(1+o(1))\frac{\ln n}{\ln \ln n}$ with high probabilty.

Does anyone know how to see this or where I could read a proof?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you gave a reference to the paper.

Comment: Sure, [Random Graphs from Planar and
Other Addable Classes by McDiarmid et al.](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/people/academic_staff/colin_mcdiarmid/?a=4086) in the proof of Corollary 5.3 on page 9.